# How to solve the following question using the provided Runge-Kutta method in python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, runge-kutta

The question body:

> A skydiver of mass *m* in a vertical free fall experiences an aerodynamic drag force *F=cy'²* ('*c* times *y* prime square') where *y* is measured downward from the start of the fall, and *y* is a function of time (*y'* denotes the derivative of *y* w.r.t time). The differential equation describing the fall is:
>
> *y''=g-(c/m)y'²*
>
> (where *g = 9.80665* m/s^2; *c = 0.2028* kg/m; *m = 80* kg). And *y(0)=y'(0)=0* as this is a free fall.
>
> **Task:** The function must return the time of a fall of x meters, where x is the parameter of the function. The values of *g*, *c* and *m* are given below.

The Runge-Kutta function is defined as follows:

```
from numpy import *
def runge_kutta_4(F, x0, y0, x, h):
   '''
   Return y(x) given the following initial value problem:
   y' = F(x, y)
   y(x0) = y0 # initial conditions
   h is the increment of x used in integration
   F = [y'[0], y'[1], ..., y'[n-1]]
   y = [y[0], y[1], ..., y[n-1]]
   '''
   X = []
   Y = []
   X.append(x0)
   Y.append(y0)
   while x0 < x:
       k0 = F(x0, y0)
       k1 = F(x0 + h / 2.0, y0 + h / 2.0 * k0)
       k2 = F(x0 + h / 2.0, y0 + h / 2 * k1)
       k3 = F(x0 + h, y0 + h * k2)
       y0 = y0 + h / 6.0 * (k0 + 2 * k1 + 2.0 * k2 + k3)
       x0 += h
       X.append(x0)
       Y.append(y0)
   return array(X), array(Y)
```

And this is what I've done so far:

```
def prob_1_8(x)
    g = 9.80665  # m/s**2
    c = 0.2028  # kg/m
    m = 80  # kg

    def F(x, y):
        return array([
            y[1],
            g - (c / m) * ((y[1]) ** 2)
        ])

    X, Y = runge_kutta_4(F, 0, array([0, 0]), 5000, 1000)
    for i in range(len(X)):
        if X[i] == 5000:
            return Y[i]
```

However, when I tried to print prob_1_8(5000), the number looks ridiculous and it displayed:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars.
```

According to the answer provided, I should get a value close to 84.8 when *x=5000*. Can someone help me with this? I don't know what's the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please contemplate the function call of `X, Y = runge_kutta_4(F, 0, array([0, 0]), 5000, 1000)`. You are integrating over a time span of `5000 sec > 1 hour` in steps of `1000 sec > 16 min`. It is intuitively clear that this will be imprecise, as most of the acceleration will happen in the first 10 sec.

---

Then the question is what exactly you are trying to filter out with the loop. Is it the speed after this time?

---

The limit speed is where the right side is zero, at `vmax=sqrt(g*m/c) = 62.1972 = 223.91 km/h`, the claimed value of `84.8` can not be reached as a speed starting from rest. The fall time to a distance of `x` will be a little more than `x/vmax`, so you could use `tmax = 100+x/vmax` in `T, Y = runge_kutta_4(F, t0, y0, tmax, 1)`.

---

Integrating in 1 sec time steps and looking for the speed after 5000 meters fall distance gives a result of `85 sec`, distance `5013.33465614 m`, speed `62.1972 m/s` which is as to be expected close to the limit speed.

You can get a more precise time value by using (reverse) linear interpolation, then at time about `84.786 sec` you reach distance `5000 m` with a speed `62.1972 m/s`. This again is compatible with the claimed result value, which now is a time, not a velocity.